# Automatically setting image width and height with Coin slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery [coinslider](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/) , What I am looking for is to fix the image size and height , Is there any plugins out there which can automatically change the height and width of an image to certain pixels.

```
<div id='coin-slider'>

<a href="#" target="_blank">

    <img src='@img01.jpg' > //size should be 960 x 305 , cant use height and width as it will disturb the pixel definition  </a> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wana change the image size and hight generaly just do it in the instalation of coinslider

```
$('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 960, height: 305 });
```

Comment: setting the width and height doesnt change the size of image it changes the size of panel

Comment: I have used imagegen to solve this issue, works like a charm :)

Comment: @MrA is there a way to set the _panel_ (as you said) width and height in the CSS without explicitly setting it in the JavaScript as seen in this answer? I've tried several ideas and none have worked..

Answer (score 1):

**Answered the question here:**

> [Resize issue with coin slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860313/resize-issue-with-coin-slider/17727705)