# Resize issue with coin slider

Tags: jquery

I have gallery using coin slider

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $jq(window).load(function() { 
        var imheight = $jq(window).height()-40;
        var imwidth = imheight / 1.5;
        $jq('#placeholder').css({'width':imwidth+'px','height':imheight+'px','margin-left':'-'+imwidth/2+'px','margin-top':'-'+imheight/2+'px'});
        $jq('#vslider').coinslider({ 
          width:imwidth, 
          height:imheight, 
          spw: 6, 
          sph: 4, 
          delay: 2500, 
          sDelay: 30, 
          opacity: 0.7, 
          titleSpeed: 1500, 
          effect: '', 
          navigation: false, 
          links : true, 
          hoverPause: false, 
          stopAtLastSlide: true 
        });
 })
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder">
  <div id="vslider">
    <a href="/main"><img src="/preload/2.jpg" alt="701" /></a>
    <a href="/main"><img src="/preload/1.jpg" alt="563" /></a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Placeholder div loads with correct width and height. 
But vslider doesn't change it's size.
What can it be?

Comment: Did you forget the semicolon at the end, or was that just a typo?

Comment: @Zalk not really gonna be an issue here. ASI will take care of it. although if it is not a typo, for sensibility it should be added.

Comment: Just to narrow it down a bit. Could you try with `$jq('#vslider').coinslider()` and see if it's working? Also, are you loading the jquery js before the coinslider js, as this guy didn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472724/jquery-coin-slider-not-working-at-all

Comment: Of course, jquery is loaded. Slider works, but images doesn't feet into  placeholder div

Comment: Decided to use Nivo Slider. It works fine

Answer (score 4):

I've had some trouble trying to do the same.
After a lot of digging, I found how to do this.

Suppose you have the following coin-slider panel:

```
            <div id="banner_slideshow">
                <a href="#1">
                    <img src="header-image-bg1.jpg" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
```

coin-slider will generate a class called `cs-<container-id>`, in this case `cs-banner_slideshow` for each "square" that is used for animation drawing.

It actually removes the `<img>` you put, and replaces it with background-equivalent image.

So basically all you need to do is put this in your **.js**:

```
$('#banner_slideshow').coinslider({
    width: 1000, // width of slider panel
    height: 350, // height of slider panel
});

// Resize picture.
$('.cs-banner_slideshow').css('background-size', '1000px 350px');
```

(You could also do this in a .css file, but I find it more suitable for the javascript file because it accesses the internal implementation of coin-slider, and I don't want that in my style sheet files).

And in your **.css**:

```
#banner_slideshow {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1000px 350px;
}
```